# NativeModules.RNRadar remains undefined after installing native SDK

Tags: ios, react-native

When running on the iOS emulator any Radar function produces a "NativeModules.RNRadar is undefined" error. I have followed the SDK instructions for iOS. I have not installed for Android.

The app, which is just the basic rn template app, runs fine until I call Radar.

1. Start clean project using rn typescript template.
2. Follow SDK installation [instructions](https://radar.io/documentation/sdk#ios-configure) from Radar docs.
3. Install RN package and follow installation [instructions](https://github.com/radarlabs/react-native-radar).
4. Call Radar from `App.tsx` in `componentDidMount`.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**Update:**
In the Plist screenshot you'll see an empty string for one of the privacy settings. I put in a string and it didn't change anything.

The errors in `AppDelegate` don't have an effect at runtime.

Answer (score 1):

I was missing the @ string prefix in `initializeWithPublishableKey` but somehow the native code was compiling.

From the accompanying GitHub [thread](https://github.com/radarlabs/react-native-radar/issues/51)...

> Yeah, this is very odd as that native could shouldn't even compile;
>   the string literal in [Radar initializeWithPublishableKey:"key"]
>   should fail, should be [Radar initializeWithPublishableKey:@"key"].
>   I've noticed that react native builds can fail but the toolchain still
>   pushes an old version of the .app to the simulator, its worth double
>   checking that your build is succeeding.